# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo - Android

Tags: java, android, xml, firebase-authentication

I'm creating a mobile application for android and I have a problem when after the download connection by Google

the application crashes. Could someone give me a reason and how to attach it?

Main activities within reach.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
private int RC_SIGN_IN = 3;
SignInButton signInButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    signInButton = findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);

    signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.sign_in_button:
                    signIn();
                    break;
                // ...
            }
        }
    });
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

}
private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        // The Task returned from this call is always completed, no need to attach
        // a listener.
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(task);
    }
}
private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
    try {
        GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MenuActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ApiException e) {
        // The ApiException status code indicates the detailed failure reason.
        // Please refer to the GoogleSignInStatusCodes class reference for more information.
        Log.w("TAG", "signInResult:failed code=" + e.getStatusCode());
        // updateUI(null);
    }
}
```

}

Target activity after logging in:

```
public class MenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
Button logoutBtn;
TextView userName;
ImageView profileImage;
private GoogleSignInOptions gso;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

    logoutBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_wyl);
    profileImage=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.profileImage);
    userName = findViewById(R.id.name);
    logoutBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                // ...
                case R.id.button_wyl:
                    signOut();
                    break;
                // ...
            }
        }
    });

    GoogleSignInAccount acct = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
    if (acct != null) {
        String personName = acct.getDisplayName();
        Uri personPhoto = acct.getPhotoUrl();

        userName.setText(personName);
        Glide.with(this).load(String.valueOf(personPhoto)).into(profileImage);

    }
}

private void signOut() {
    mGoogleSignInClient.signOut()
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    Toast.makeText(MenuActivity.this, "Signed out Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();
                }
            });
}
```

}

Exception:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.goodmath, PID: 1780
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.goodmath/com.example.goodmath.MenuActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
>   on a null object reference
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
>   on a null object reference
>           at com.example.goodmath.MenuActivity.onCreate(MenuActivity.java:46)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
>   I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 1780 SIG: 9

Answer (score 2):

You do not call `setContentView()` in `onCreate()` of `MenuActivity`, so your `findViewById()` lookups will fail. As a result, `logoutBtn` is `null`, so you crash with a `NullPointerException` when you try calling a method on it.

Comment: logoutBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_wyl);
        profileImage=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.profileImage);
        userName = findViewById(R.id.name);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

Comment: @Lamps: Call `setContentView()` first, before calling `findViewById()`.

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
logoutBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_wyl);

Comment: @Lamps: Then you do not have a widget in `res/layout/activity_menu.xml` with `android:id="@+id/button_wyl"`, apparently.

Answer (score 2):

The actual error is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void 
android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' 
on a null object
```

So findViewById fails.

Do `setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu)` directly after super.onCreate()

And if that doesn't work, are you sure that the view you are referencing is within the activity_menu layout file?